# MySQL relation inserts

Tags: mysql

I've a relational MySQL database setup like this:

```
COMMAND              SOURCE            DESTINATION
id                   id                id
datetime             name              name
source_id            location_id       data_type
destination_id

LOCATION             
id
name
```

There may be many sources and destinations to commands and many locations to sources.

I receive a command with the following values (command ID auto increments):

```
datetime = 12345671234
source = "source_device_one"
destination = "destination_device_one"
```

I need a way that when inserting the command values into the database, the program checks whether "source_device_one" is a name that already exists in the SOURCE table and if so gets the ID of it, if not it inserts it into the table and retrieves the ID for the command insert. The same would need to be done for the destination device too.

I know I could do separate queries programmatically (in python/php by first checking if each device exists in their respective tables and get its ID/insert it if not) but this would take quite a few queries/lines of code- the system I am trying to create needs to be as quick and efficient as possible as it's reading commands from a stream.

I would be very interested to hear your input on which would be the best way to do this.

Many thanks.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0):

Cheers to Digital Chris- I'd already seen that page but you confirmed to me that I should look into that more. Roughly my solution:

```
INSERT INTO source(name) VALUES ('box1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=last_insert_id(id);
SET @source = last_insert_id();
INSERT INTO destination(name) VALUES ('hole1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=last_insert_id(id);
SET @dest = last_insert_id();
INSERT INTO command(datetime,source_id,destination_id) VALUES(NOW(), @source, @dest)
```

Working fast enough for me so far!